# Windows 2008: DHCP server with "holes"

Tags: windows, dhcp-server

I have a Windows 2008 server.
This server as the DHCP role.
The LAN is 192.168.0.0/**23** (from 192.168.**0**.0 to 192.168.**1**.255 with netmask 255.255.25**4**.0).
The DHCP currently distributes addresses from 192.168.0.50 to 192.168.0.249 with netmask 255.255.25**4**.0

I want to add more available addresses. Free addresses are from 192.168.1.50 to 192.168.1.219

How can I distribute addresses from 2 non-contiguous zones?
Create 2 "scopes"?
Or create one big scope, with a hole in the middle?

I tried with a global scope, but Windows refuse the second scope because it consider it overlap with the existing scope (which is not true, but the netmask probably confuse it).

A solution could be to create a big scope, then make a lot of reservations to create the hole. But this is a tedious task, an not smart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you can do this is increase your existing DHCP scope to the entire 192.168.0.0/23 network and then create exceptions for the blocks of addresses you want to use as static IP addresses.

Comment: So simple. I forgot the fact we can make exclusion. Thanks :)